# How to bind to an entire UI Element?

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, dependency-properties

I have a custom control which contains a `WebView`. I also have a ViewModel which takes in a WebView in the constructor and modifies it. It passes the `WebView` control to the VM where it is modified.

Originally, I wanted to do this:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AccountProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("Account", typeof(Account), typeof(AccountViewControl),
           new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public Account Account {
        get { return (Account)GetValue(AccountProperty); }
        set {
            SetValue(AccountProperty, value);
            SiteViewModel SiteVM = new SiteViewModel(wv: wvAccount);
            SiteVM.CurrentAccount = value;
            SiteVM.LoginToSite();
        }
    }
```

Each control has a `WebView` named `wvAccount` which would be passed into the `SiteViewModel` constructor. However, since the setter is bypassed when using a `DependencyProperty`, I have to use a static `PropertyChanged` event to call `SiteVM.LoginToSite` which won't have access to the WebView within the control's XAML.

My first thought was to add a `WebView` property to the SiteVM and bind the UI's `WebView` to that element, however, I can't seem to find any way to bind to an entire UI element.

Here's what I want to achieve:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SiteViewModelProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Account", typeof(SiteViewModel), typeof(AccountViewControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, OnSiteViewModelChanged));

private static void OnSiteViewModelChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    SiteViewModel siteVM = (SiteViewModel)e.NewValue;
    siteVM.LoginToSite();
}
```

And I would bind it like so:

```
<WebView {x:Bind=SiteVM.WebView} Visibility="{Binding ShowEditControl, ElementName=accountControl, Converter={ThemeResource InverseVisConverter}}" x:Name="wvAccount" />
```

Is there perhaps a way (or better way) to achieve this?

Comment: In your OnSiteViewModelChanged the d parameter would be your WebView.  Have you tried to cast it and use it?

Comment: Do you mean that the 'd' parameter is the instance of the control class? I'm at work, but I'll give it a shot when I get a home?

Comment: Well I'll be damned... it worked! Appreciate it mate. If you want to create and answer, I'll be sure to mark it as the answer :)

Comment: I assumed the `DependencyObject` would be the `Account` property, not the entire `Custom Control`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, I think most developers would agree that this is a bad idea. That doesn't mean you can't do it, though. Let's pretend your element is named MyElement. Do this:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:MyViewModel Element="{Binding, ElementName=MyElement}" />
</Page.DataContext>
```

Just remember that the Element property you create in your ViewModel is of type UIElement or the actual element type if you want it to be more strongly-typed.

Best of luck!

Comment: Luckily, I was trying to make the problem more complex that it was and I could access the element by casting the `DependencyObject` as the `MyElement` control. Appreciate the help, Jerry.